# destring 18 digit number returns rounding error

Tags: stata

I have IDs with a length of 18 as strings and I want to transform them to a numeric variable.
I tried the follwoing code:

```
destring var, replace
```

That returns the variable with a numeric format. However, the last digit of the ID includes a rounding error. E.g.: 123456789123456000 --> 123456789123456001

How can I `destring` my values without any change in the ID?

Comment: Why do you want to do arithmetic on identifiers? There should be direct ways to manipulate identifiers using string functions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce that as this shows:

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen test = "123456789123456000"

. destring, gen(check)
test: all characters numeric; check generated as double

. l

     +--------------------------------+
     |               test       check |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. | 123456789123456000   1.235e+17 |
     +--------------------------------+

. format check %23.0f

. l

     +-----------------------------------------+
     |               test                check |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. | 123456789123456000   123456789123456000 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

The other way round does produce error as the string "123456789123456001" maps to 123456789123456000. In essence, you are bumping up against what can be held exactly in a `double` with 8 bytes for each number.